# PHP cURL to many urls

Tags: php, curl

I have php a code and can't understand why the php script creates only 4 files, but without the data. If I use curl only for one url without foreach loop all will be ok. Any thoughts?

```
$years = array('2012', '2013', '2014', '2015');
foreach($years as $year)
{
    $url = "http://lpo.dt.navy.mil/data/DM/Environmental_Data_Deep_Moor_{$year}.txt";
    $fp = fopen(base_path() . "/database/rawdata/{$year}.txt", 'w');

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
        CURLOPT_FILE            => $fp,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => 1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
        CURLOPT_FAILONERROR     => 1
    ));

    curl_exec($curl);

    if (!curl_errno($curl))
    {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        Log::info("File created  {$year}.txt");
        Log::notice("Evaluation of this script was {$info['total_time']} seconds!");
    }
    else
    {
        Log::error("cURL ERROR " . curl_error($curl));
    }

    curl_close($curl);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: You should make an [edit] and include your code.

Comment: Where's the code that uses `$fp` ? you don't seem to have any code that handle the file write so why wouldn't it be empty?

Comment: CURLOPT_FILE            => $fp,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See joeterranova's [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#99082) on the PHP site:

> It appears that setting `CURLOPT_FILE` before setting
>   `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` doesn't work, presumably because
>   `CURLOPT_FILE` depends on `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` being set

.

Therefore you should change your `curl_setopt_array` to the following:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_FILE            => $fp,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => 1,
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR     => 1
));
```